# BizTalk XSLT Map - Execution of scripts was prohibited

Tags: visual-studio, xslt, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I'm programming with **BizTalk Server 2020** (Visual Studio 2019).

I have this xsl code (simplified), that is in an external xsl file of a btm map:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
                xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var userCSharp" version="1.0" 
                xmlns:ns0="http://Schema1/EDI/EDIFACT/2006" 
                xmlns:ns1="http://Schema2.schCanonical"
                xmlns:userCSharp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/userCSharp">
                
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/ns0:EFACT" />
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="/ns0:EFACT">
    <ns1:schCanonical>
      <xsl:variable name="var:v1" select="userCSharp:StringConcat(&quot;VariableOne&quot;)" />
    ...
    </ns1:schCanonical>
  </xsl:template>
  
  
  <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="userCSharp">
  <![CDATA[
  
public string StringConcat(string param0)
{
   return param0;
}

  ]]>
  </msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that on *var:v1* declaration I have this **warning**:

> Execution of scripts was prohibited. Use the XsltSettings.EnableScript property to enable it.

These are BTM GRID configurations:

- **Custom Extension XML:** "externalObject.xml"
- **Custom XSLT Path:** "*xsl file with above code*"
- **XSLT Trasform engine:** Undefined

The *externalObject.xml* code is:

```
<ExtensionObjects />
```

This is the error:

[image: This is the error:]

[image]

My fear is that if I were to implement other functions, this error could affect the correct transformation output.

How can I fix it?

Comment: It  could be just a warning.  What happens when you either test the map in Visual Studio, or when it is deployed to BizTalk and executed by the runtime?

Comment: When I test the map, warnings are displayed for each script call, vice versa no tests have been performed with the deploy yet. I would like to solve the problem to have a "clean" solution.
Some xsl files are complex, so I see the sheet full of warnings, and even the console when I test the maps.

Comment: Someone can help please? Next week a solution will start in Production environment, and I wanna solve the issue.